# Display loading notification or gif during an operation in a Cocoa app (not cocoa touch)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an app in which I am uploading data from a device, while the device is being read I would like to display a little loading notification or overlay. Does Cocoa have something like this built in? If I'm not mistaken I believe cocoa touch used to. Basically on a button event that starts the device reading I would also like to fire off the overlay.

The code I would add to is below:

```
- (IBAction)uploadEvent:(id)sender
{
    // start loading overlay    

    char *encodedBuffer = NULL;
    HEM6310FDriver *driver = [[HEM6310FDriver alloc] init];

    int getDataFromDevice = [driver getData:encodedBuffer user: 1];
    if (getDataFromDevice == Success) {
            int status = upload(driver.deviceData);

            //remove loading overlay
    }
    else{
          // do something else and remove overlay
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate thing to do is to add an NSProgressIndicator to your view hierarchy and display and animate when the request begins. 
If it is a determinate progress, use callbacks to update. 
You should also setEnabled: NO on views and controls that need the data until progress is complete.

You might also look at the new NSProgress API

Comment: Will have to check out the NSProgress API, wonder if it works on OSX 10.7

Answer (score 1):

Create a `NSPanel`. It can be as simple as you want. Maybe just a label that says "Loading" and a NSProgressView in indeterminate mode. You can then attach it to the window like this:

```
 [[NSApplication sharedApplication] beginSheet:loadingPanel
                                   modalForWindow:self.window
                                    modalDelegate:self
                                   didEndSelector:nil
                                      contextInfo:nil];
```

When you want to dismiss it, do this:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] endSheet:loadingPanel returnCode:0];
[loadingPanel orderOut:nil];
```

Comment: would this method cover the whole screen or just a small area that I determine? I have very little UIKit experience everything I have done with Objective-c has been more on the backend side of things and driver implementations.

Comment: You can set an NSPanel to be any size you want